# Does UnboundID SCIM SDK 1.8.14 has proxy support?

Tags: scim, scim2, scimore

I am using Unbound SCIM SDK 1.8.14 and trying to connect with proxy server setting but getting timeOut.
Whether it support proxy?

I have setup my WebLogic container to use http proxy.  This is the error that I receive
com.unboundid.scim.sdk.ServerErrorException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

I also digged down into the sdk code and was not able to find any proxy related code in the SCIMService class.

Comment: I think that depends on your proxy and how it is used. Can you provide more details as to what how your proxy works?

Comment: I am not aware of any issues using the SDK through a proxy. What special code did you expect the SCIM code to have?

Comment: I also received this from one my engineers (Jacob Childress): When you create a SCIMService instance, you can give it a Jersey ClientConfig object. It should be possible to set up the ClientConfig to use a proxy.